# Unable to get request using https proxies

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

**Hello, so I am trying to get requests to some https page using proxies, but it gives me an error.**

I tried couple of proxies from http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/https/ping/all and other free proxy lists
but none of them works (only http)

```
import requests

proxies = [
 {
    "https" : "207.236.12.76:10458"
 }
]

url = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json"

for proxy in proxies:
    resp = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)
    print(resp.text)
```

This gives me this:

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

When i tried adding https like {"https" : "https://207.236.12.76:10458" }:

```
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
```

Am I doing something wrong or the proxies just doesn't work?

Comment: It probably just means that the proxies are dead

Comment: Yea, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Before implementation I'd suggest you check all proxies by curl
like this

```
curl -v -L "https://2ip.ru/" -x "https://205.207.100.81:8282"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).